# "New" adjective in comparative form

Tags: adjectives, comparison, comparative

There's a rule about one-syllable adjectives that end in a single vowel and a consonant, that duplicates the consonant in the comparative form:

big --> big**g**er

hot --> hot**t**er

I've been asking around to native english speakers and nobody seems to recall this specific rule, and the odd thing is it doesn't apply in the adjective "new":

new --> newer, not new**w**er

So, some students were wondering why "new" isn't considered an irregular adjective like bad (worse instead of "badder"), good (better instead of goodder), etc..

Usually I look up in a *"A practical English Grammar" by Audrey Jean Thomson,
A.V. Martinet, Oxford University Press - Fourth Edition* to answer all my doubts, but this one keeps on puzzling me.

Answer (score 1):

**Your rule is too simple to be correct**

1. Very few words in English have "ww" in them. In fact 99% of the words that do, are compound nouns that could be written as separate words or hyphenated. I think the only verbs with ""ww" are "bowwow" and "powwow"  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-ww
2. The letter "w" is a semi-vowel. Here's an article that explains further [When Is "W" a Vowel?](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-is-w-a-vowel)
3. I surmise also that there are few to zero doublings  when it comes to adjectives ending in *h, y and x*

Maybe you could come up with your own rule?